# solving a linear matrix equation where the variable appears in a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

For constant $m \times 1$ vectors $c$ and $d$, constant $m \times n$ matrix $Z$, and variable $n \times 1$ vector $x$, I want to solve the following for $x$:
$$\left[\left(d^{T}diag(Zx)-c^{T}\right)Z\right]^{T}=0$$

I have searched for answers to similar questions on this site, and I am guessing that the answer may involve vectorization and the Kronecker product, but I think that the diagonalization operator is causing me trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

Form an $m \times n$ matrix $P$, each column $j$ of which is equal to $-diag(Z^{<j>}d)$, where $Z^{<j>}$ denotes the $j$th column of $Z$.  The solution is then given by $-(P^{T}Z)^{-1}Z^{T}c$.